# How to add quantity based product prices in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

How to add quantity based product prices in Prestashop?. for example there is a product and price depends on the quantity. So if the product is `"Honey"` and quantity is 100gms its 20$ and if its 200gms then its 18$ etc.

And also how to import these data?

Answer (score 2):

On product editing page, go to `"prices tab"` and then bellow to `"specific prices"`.

-> There you can add a new specific price and specify the minimum quantity to get this price.

You have to create a specific price for each discount quantity.

Comment: I want to add product price look like 100gm=20$,200gm=36$,300gm=51$

Comment: That's the only way I know. Doing like this, you'll have a table label "Quantity discounts" on the product page. After adding a discounted quantity, you we'll see the discounted price in the cart summary. _Note : You don't have to specify a start and end date_.